# How to export and format my result from MySQL database into excel

Tags: python, mysql, parsing, openpyxl

I've not been able to find anything on how to export my results from MySQL query into excel. In the results there is just 1 field/row that needs to formatted correctly. So, this is how it comes out from the code I'm using, all in 1 long line, with the separators.

```
[('number_of_journeys,distinct_ships,"GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sj.ship_id SEPARATOR \';\')","GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.ship_type_name SEPARATOR \';\')"\n536,13,6713283;9155913;9219898;9253442;9277321;9282558;9292113;9437866;9515034;10008511;10008693;10017790;10027359,"GENERAL CARGO (Deck Cargo);HANDY BC;HANDYMAX BC;MGC LPG;MR2 TNKR;PANAMAX CONT;SINGLEDECKER (Open Hatch);SMALL CRUISE LUXURY;SMALL HANDY BC (Open Hatch / Self Disc)"\n',)]
```

Now, this is different to when I export directly from the database I'm using, as that comes out in the format of:
[excel table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrs53.png). And this is the format that I want to be able to export it into.

*Note: I've been able to actually export to excel, but just not in the format that I want. My output goes into a single cell in excel, whereas I need to split out the fields by comma separated values and also by the newlines.

The code I'm using is below, I've just left out the config details:

```
try:
  myConnection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
    cursor = myConnection.cursor(buffered=True)
    query = ("SELECT t.results FROM tbl_trade_health_checks_2021_04_26 t WHERE t.order = 2")
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    df = pd.read_sql(query, myConnection)
    print(df)
    df.to_excel('SqlTester.xlsx')
    cursor.close()
    myConnection.close()
```

Comment: You can try [MySQL for Excel](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/), I am not going to look at the code, to see what exactly you need in formatting this XLS file.

Comment: What does `the format that I want.` or `split out the fields by comma separated values` mean? `df.to_excel` will store each DataFrame cell into a separate Excel cell. There are no commas involved. You don't even need to use `openpyxl` directly. You could write `query = "...";  df=pd.read_sql(query,muConnection); df.to_excel('...');` What does `results` contain?

Comment: If you want to export the data in separate cells why are you using `GROU_CONCAT` to aggregate them into a single cell? You'll have to split that string to get back the original values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This one field that I have exported from the database, is a table of data in itself (That's just how it works). What I want to do is separate the first 4 values by comma (which you can see that they are) and these then become the headers of the table that you can see in the imgur picture I linked. Then the next 4 fields, which you can see are denoted after the '\n' are then also all separated by comma (and these will be the values under each table header). `results` contains that first line of code in my original post. And I want to go from that to the table format I posted.

Comment: @BruSwain that's a serious database design bug, not a `just how it works`. That violates the most basic design rule. This has nothing to do with MySQL or Excel. You have to split that *string value* into proper rows and cells and store *that* in an Excel file. If the string had a common format, eg JSON, or CSV,  you could read it directly into a frame with `read_json`, `read_csv` etc. Otherwise you'll have to write your own parsing code to convert that string to values. What you posted looks like a mix of tuples, arrays, semicolon-separated values

Comment: @BruSwain This is 100% a parsing question. Post a *well formatted* example of the actual string, so people can understand its structure without having to scroll. Explain what  that format contains, if you know it. Why is there a ` GROUP_CONCAT` in the data? Escape sequences? Does that string contain column names or metadata? What is the metadata and what is the data you want to export?

Comment: @BruSwain how was that string created? Chances are that whoever *serialized* the data also has a deserializer to read the data. Or not - the string starts with `[('` but ends with `,')]`. There are no obvious record or field separators. It looks like once these delimiters are removed you have two column names without separators, then the expressions that generated the data surrounded by double quotes, then a semicolon-separated least of Column1 values, then a double-quoted list of strings separated by commas. That's .... messy.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can already export my data into excel from the database, using the built in functions already from the program Heidi, in the following picture: [link](https://imgur.com/a/hPc4m6n)

Comment: @BruSwain there's *no Excel option at all* there. There's no such thing as an `Excel CSV`. That's a hack some applications and sites use - export a CSV file with a fake `xls` extension and hope Excel can import the file when it's double-clicked. It often fails because Excel will use the current user's locale to retrieve field, list and decimal separators and date formats.

Comment: @BruSwain an `xlsx` file is a ZIP package containing XML files with a specific format. It's not affected by encodings (the XML files are always UTF8) or separators.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe what I'm asking for is not possible then, thanks though.

Comment: @BruSwain quite the opposite, it's very easy to generate a real `xlsx` file once you have the data. `df.to_excel` is all it takes. You just don't have that data yet. You have one long string in a custom format. Once you parse that string into rows and fields you can easily write it to Excel. If you had a proper table all you'd need would be `df=pd.read_sql(query,connection); df.to_excel(somePath);`.

Comment: @BruSwain the problem is the custom format, not MySQL or Excel. If the data was in JSON, you could easily flatten it with [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). You'll have to write your own code to parse that string and return a dataframe with the columns and data contained in that string